# Redirect output back to terminal in C

Tags: c, shell, posix

```
    if (out) {
            out = 0;
            int fd = open(output_file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
            if (fd == -1) perror("open for writing");
            if (dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO) < 0) { perror("dup2"); abort();}
            close(fd);
    }

    if (-1 == execvp(argv[0], argv)) {
      perror("execvp");
      printf("  (couldn't find command)\n");
    }



    exit(1);
```

I am trying to redirect output back into terminal after redirecting it to a separate file. At the moment, this works when I call:

```
$ ls > file.txt
```

However, when I call

```
$ ls -l
```

right afterwards, it continues to direct its output into file.txt, rather than the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get the original standard output back after closing all copies of it.

Normally, if you are going to exec another program with redirected output, you first `fork()` a child, and apply the redirection only in the child, then have the child terminate immediately if the exec fails.  The parent's streams are unaffected that way, so there is no need to restore them.  This is what shells do when they run external commands.

But to answer the question posed, if you want to be able to redirect the standard output and then later restore it, you need to make a copy of it first ...

```
int stdout_save = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
```

Then perform your redirection.  When ready to restore, just copy the saved file descriptor back, and close the dupe.

```
dup2(stdout_save, STDOUT_FILENO);
close(stdout_save);
```

Do not neglect to perform proper checks on the return values of these function calls; I have omitted that from the example code for clarity and brevity.

Comment: I'm sorry, @yoonpatrick3, but I do not accept that the code now presented in the question is responsible for the effect you describe.  There is nothing a process can do that will directly affect the memory of its parent process or of any of its sibling processes, past or future.  That includes their file descriptor tables.  The only weird thing there is that in the case of an `execve()` failure, the message from `perror()` will go to `stderr`, but the supplementary `printf` message will go to possibly-redirected `stdout`.

Comment: But it also follows, then, that the `out = 0` that the child performs has no effect on the parent.  Perhaps the problem is not that any redirection has to be reversed, but that the parent process needs to be told not to redirect the next command, too.

Comment: I believe that the `out = 0` that the child performs has no effect on the parent. By moving `out = 0` into the same function that checks whether or not  `>` exists in the read line, it seems to be working. Thank you.